# Invalid `Podfile` file: Operation not supported on socket error

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I get this error when trying to run on iPhone 11 pro max - 13.2.2 simulator.

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...

> ```
> Running pod install...CocoaPods' 
> output:
>     ↳ [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: Operation not supported on socket @ rb_file_s_symlink -
> ```
>
> (/Users/x/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine, .symlinks/flutter).
>
> ## from /Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/C/app/ios/Podfile:51
>
> -------------------------------------------  #        symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
>
> > ```
> >    File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)  #        pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))  #
> > ```
>
> ---
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:301:in
> `rescue in block in from_ruby' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:295:in` block in from_ruby'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in
> `instance_eval' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in` initialize'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in
> `new' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:293:in` from_ruby'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:259:in
> `from_file' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:200:in` podfile'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:150:in
> `verify_podfile_exists!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in` run'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
> `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in` run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in
> `<top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` load'
> /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'
>
> Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro
> Max.

---

```
pod --version
1.8.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error when my files was stored in Windows NTFS and I was trying to access it from MAC, to resolve the issue I moved the folder from Windows NTFS partition to my Desktop.

The symlink error appears when your MAC is unable to create symbolic link file on unsupported partition.