# Flutter iOS Build Issue : l[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries:

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

Recently I am getting a build issue with Flutter iOS. It was working fine before, now for all flutter applications i try to build iOS same build issue arises.

**Flutter Version : 1.17.5**

**Xcode Version : 11.3.1**

**Mac Os : 10.15**

On `pod install` getting the following error message

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (/Users/acube/Desktop/Projects/Uhlala /limitless_singlevendor-app/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework)
```

**And in Xcode Build**

> error: /Users/acube/Desktop/Projects/Uhlala /limitless_singlevendor-app/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

**I have already tried almost all available fixes found in stack and github**

1. add

> **s.static_framework = true**

2. Clean build and pod
3. Uninstall flutter,xcode

**Flutter Doctor result**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A583, locale en-GB)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this problem in all my project even I Create a new flutter Project. Finally I found the solution .

**Solution**

I strongly believe that this issue caused because of some configuration or flutter install issues. I have solved this issue by uninstalling all flutter and coco pods from the machine and reinstalling all from scratch.
Then deleting the ios folder from the project and create it again using **flutter create .** command.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this over the weekend. My solution was to rejig the platform architecture; rather than rewriting the code. So uninstalling & reinstalling Flutter, Cocoa-pods (& even Xcode if needed).

I've posted a step-by-step solution below.. if anyone's still stuck.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64203751/3543789